# Convert all words from lowercase letter to capital letter (with Diacritics / Accent Marks)

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I want to change multiple text files, convert all words from lowercase letter to capital letter, with `Find In Files and replace all` option.

I try this regex:

- FIND: `(.*)([A-Z]+)`
- REPLACE BY: `\L$1$2`

My regex is almost good, because it changes all letters from all words - except Diacritics (Accent Marks). So, the problem is that all letter diacritic remain unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

With Sublime Text:

- Find: `(\p{L})`
- Replace: `\U\1`

**Explanation**

- `(\p{L})`: 1st capturing group
- `\p{L}` matches any kind of letter from any language
- `\U`: upper case
- `\1`: content of 1st captured group

Comment: It doesn't work for me, `àùûç` is still `àùûç`. `évènement` becomes `éVèNEMENT` instead of `ÉVÈNEMENT`. According to [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MemxPt/1) it works with PCRE but not with PCRE2 !!!!

Comment: not working. See this example: `Un pătrat negru în albul orbitor reflectă darul viziunii` All lowercase letter (with diacritics) didn't change.

Comment: Sorry, I tested it with Notepad++ I haven't noticed you're using SublimeText ;) It definitly works and there is a problem with Notepad++.

Comment: Just a remark it's more efficient to use a quantifier `\p{L}+` and process only lowercase `\p{Ll}+` but it seems SublimeText doesn't support `\p{Ll}`

Comment: doesn't work in notepad++ (the letters with diacritics didn't change)

Comment: @Toto Thanks for the remark. I will definitely try to use `\p{L}+` or `\p{Ll}` in the future.

Comment: @RobRob It does not work in Notepad++ but does in Sublime Text (you have Sublime Text as one of your tags) .

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio ok, works in sublime. But, another case. The contrary. If I want to convert all worlds from "capital letters" to "lowercase" , what is the regex for this case ?